# Improving 10-to-8bit-conversion performance

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

I have greyscale image file with 10 bit data.
The 10 bit are saved over 2 bytes, low-bit aligned (the 10 bit Value `0b10 0000 1111` is saved as `0x020F`.

I want to convert this to 8bit, keeping the most significant byte.

```
def convert_10bitTo8Bit(tenBitData):
    output_size = int(len(tenBitData) / 2)
    eightBitData = bytearray(output_size)
    for i in range(output_size):
        lowbyte, highbyte = tenBitData[i * 2 + 1], tenBitData[i * 2]
        value = (highbyte << 8) + lowbyte
        value = (value >> 2) & 0xff
        eightBitData[i] = value
    return eightBitData
```

This works, but is pretty slow: For a 3MB Image it takes around 0.5 seconds on my dev machine and >8 seconds on the device it's intended to run on (ARM System, similar performance to a PI).

I tried to profile it to find the bottleneck, but cProfile just reports builtins.exec as the most time consuming function.

```
$ python3 ImageTools.py
     5 function calls in 8.560 seconds

Ordered by: standard name

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     1    0.000    0.000    8.560    8.560 <string>:1(<module>)
     1    8.559    8.559    8.559    8.559 ImageTools.py:11(convert_10bitTo8Bit)
     1    0.000    0.000    8.560    8.560 {built-in method builtins.exec}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

How can I improve the performance?

Comment: Have you tried converting it to a 16-bit numpy array, calling `numpy.right_shift(2)` and then converting back to 8-bit?

Comment: @MarkSetchell How would you do the conversion to 16-bit numpy array in an efficient way?

Comment: @MarkSetchell your solution seems to be the fastest so far. `np.frombuffer(tenBitData, dtype=np.uint16)` and `shifted = np.right_shift(npdata8bit, 2)` result in a pretty fast result. If you format that into an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Cool - glad it works for you. It's ok, you can write it up and accept your own answer if you have coded and benchmarked it, whereas I was just a lazy monkey guessing it might be faster!

Answer (score 2):

You can improve performance by vectorizing operations using `numpy`:

```
# Store byte pairs as columns.
# If `tenBitData` is a `bytes` object, then use `np.fromiter` instead.
>>> data = np.asarray(tenBitData, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(-1, 2)

# Now we apply vectorized conversion.
>>> (data[:, 0] << 6) + (data[:, 1] >> 2)
```

When testing on my computer (4MB data) I get the following timings:

```
Conversion: 3.044390e-01s
Function: 1.002173e+00s
Numpy: 7.728000e-03s
```

So although `numpy` is fast, conversion is still a bottleneck (at least giving a factor of 3). Depending on how your data is stored initially that kind of conversion might not even be necessary.

Comment: This is already pretty fast, @MarkSetchell s solution using `np.frombuffer(tenBitData, dtype=np.uint16)` and `shifted = np.right_shift(npdata8bit, 2)` is even faster by a factor of 2-3.

Comment: @xavor Very good! Actually the greater impact of using `np.frombuffer` is that it reduces time for data conversion from `bytes` to `np.array` by 4 orders of magnitude, basically removing this bottleneck. The approach in my answer is limited by conversion speed which is only ~ 5x faster than applying the function in the OP. With `np.frombuffer` the bottleneck is again bit-shifting and so the actual speed-up of using the `np.frombuffer` approach (compared to `np.fromiter`) is a factor of ~ 60x on my computer. So that approach really deserves its own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your function name conflicts a little with what the function is actually doing, but yes it can be improved, This assumes you no longer care about the original 10 bit data. it will work for any size assuming you always have pairs of bytes, an odd number will throw an error

```
def convert_8bitTo10Bit(tenBitData):
    eightBitData = bytearray()
    while tenBitData:
        eightBitData.insert(0,((tenBitData.pop() | (tenBitData.pop() << 8)) >> 2 & 0xFF))
    return eightBitData
```

Comment: Thanks for the Name-Hint, I corrected that. Other than that, pop() does not work on bytes and when converting my bytes to bytearray(), it seems that this is much slower than my variant.